# PHP while returns same result repeatedly

Tags: php, mysql, database, while-loop, repeat

When running a while script on my local xampp it just returns the same result over and over again, here's the PHP I'm using:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getmembers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE groupid = $id LIMIT 10");
$getids = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmembers);
    while($id = $getids['userid']){
        $getusers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT look, username FROM users WHERE id = '$id'"));
        echo ($getusers['username']);
        echo('<br />');
    }
?>
```

All that I get when I execute that is: http://prntscr.com/12nh6g My database contains 4 different users registered to that group. I'm not sure about joining tables in MySQL as I have no idea how to do it.

If I add a break; then it only returns one result, instead of timing out.

Any help is much appreciated!

Also I'm sorry about how messy the PHP is, I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($id = $getids['userid']){ #This condition will always be true.
```

Use your `mysql_fetch_assoc` statement in a loop like below.

```
while ($getids = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmembers)) {
    $id = $getids['userid']
    $getusers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT look, username FROM users WHERE id = '$id'"));
    echo $getusers['username'];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

For **sub query** you can try,

```
SELECT look, username FROM users
WHERE id IN 
       (SELECT userId FROM group_memberships
        WHERE groupid = $id
        LIMIT 10)
```

Using **JOIN**,

```
SELECT u.look,u.username
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN group_memberships as gm
     on gm.userId = u.id 
     WHERE gm.groupid = $id
     LIMIT 10
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$id = (int) $_GET['id']; // very important part here, I cast the id to int, else you have a SQL injection leak
$getmembers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE groupid = $id LIMIT 10");
while ($membership = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmembers)) // on each pass we take a new result off first query
{
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT look, username FROM users WHERE id = '".$membership['user_id']."'"));
    echo ($user['username']);
    echo('<br />');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the SQL injection, much appreciated!

Comment: If looking for security use parameters with PDO or Mysqli INSTEAD of mysql_query_* - functions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getmembers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE groupid = $id LIMIT 10");
$getids = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmembers);
    while($id = $getids['userid']){
        $getusers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT look, username FROM users WHERE id = '$id'"));
        echo ($getusers['username']);
        echo('<br />');
    }
?>
```

tells PHP that **"Do the loop" while $id is ASSIGNED to the value of $getids['userid']**

Therefore you you will have a infinite loop because $id is assigned all the time (and always with the same value) $getids are never changed inside of the while-loop.

But even if $getids was about to change it would still be in an infinite loop because the loop **isn't checking if $id IS value of $getids['userid']**, it's just **assigning** the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getmembers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE groupid = $id LIMIT 10");

    while($getids = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmembers)){
    $getusers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT look, username FROM users WHERE id = '$id'"));
    echo ($getusers['username']);
    echo('<br />');
    }
?>
```

you had the while loop wrong , you need to do the feching inside while loop , so it goes till the fetching stop.